# Demo break down when try to call MPEG4Writer.o through JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, mpeg-4, mediamuxer

I am building my app demo on JellyBean(Android4.2.2), one module of the demo is write the h264 stream into mp4 file. Since the MPEG4Writer does this job in the source code, so I try to call it through JNI.

After I compile the source code, I get the MPEG4Writer.o file. In my first step, I just want to try if this way is possible. So I wrote the JNI file, which is quite easy, just creating a new instance of MPEG4Writer class:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "MPEG4Writer.h"

#define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MPEG4Writer", __VA_ARGS__)


jint Java_com_examole_brendontest_MainActivity_setup
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {

     mWriter = new MPEG4Writer("/sdcard/encode_manual.mp4");
     if (mWriter != NULL)
             LOGV("IT WORKS!!");

     return 1;
}
```

And the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE                    := JNIMPEG4Writer
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := MPEG4Writer
LOCAL_LDLIBS                    := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES                 := JNIMPEG4Writer.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then I call the function in Java:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("JNIMPEG4Writer");
}
 public static native int setup();
```

It is all right when I build the project, but it just shut down when I run it. And the log was:

```
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load JNIMPEG4Writer from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.brendontest-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.brendontest-2]: findLibrary returned null
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    at com.example.brendontest.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:12)
04-25 09:17:24.302: E/AndroidRuntime(31737):    ... 15 more
```

I really have no idea. If this way of using MPEG4Writer possible? Does anyone have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: It seems possible that the `JNIMPEG4Writer` libray is not actually deployed on the device. You have defined the library in the Android.mk, but you have not mentioned if you have added a dependency to this library e.g. to your app or to the global `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`. If the library is not explicitly specified as a dependency, it will not get build by default and therefore will not be available on the device.